# Deploy exe file into ubuntu or linux environment

Tags: wine, java, jre

I finished my java program development and converted it into exe file which I would like to execute in Ubuntu or Linux environment(Please advise if exe file is not suitable since my program don't have any GUI), I know Ubuntu have one application call WINE where allow the exe file install in Ubuntu, but when I try run the wine with my java exe file, it's show me I need java runtime environment, I believe my java environment had installed properly because this is the same machine that I used to develop my program from scratch. This is the content in my `/etc/profile`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

This is the content in `bashrc`

```
#JAVA HOME directory setup
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

I have search some information but no luck to solve this issue. Any developer can advise what is the best approach if i want to deploy java application/code into Linux(Ubuntu/red hat) ,do I need to create any shell script for my purpose?

Comment: wine prefix are quazi sandboxed. java has to be installed in the wine prefix you are running the exe in. wine

Comment: but it's still show me need java runtime environment.Able to advise troubleshooting step?